# How to search within 5 words of a keyword

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, keyword

I want to search multiple variations of the same keyword in a title, without having to list every variation.

For example, we are searching `"access to care"` `"access to healthcare"` `"healthcare access"` `"health care access"` etc.

Is there a way to write in code something like:

```
if 5 words before or after 'access' is 'health' or 'care' then 1,0
```

Comment: What technology stack / language do you want to do this with?

Comment: With MS Access SQL

Comment: Use wildcard to search.

Answer (score 0):

Your question as it stands is very broad: almost any search logic that you can conceive of can be implemented in code, it just depends on the balance of how much time & effort you wish to invest in writing the necessary code.

The implementation of the search logic depends primarily on how the search terms should be treated, for example, here are just some considerations:

- Should multiple search terms be subject to `OR` or `AND` logic? That is, should ***any*** or ***all*** of the terms be matched for a record to appear in the results? If `OR` logic is applied, then specifying more terms will broaden the search; whereas, if `AND` logic is applied, then specifying more terms will narrow the search.
- Should connecting words be ignored? For example, the `to` in `access to care`. If you implement `OR` logic, this would yield any record containing the word `to`, which could produce a multitude of irrelevant results.
- If connecting words are to be omitted, you need to decide how to determine what consistutes a word which should be omitted:

  - Should the program read such words from a stored dictionary?
  - Automatically omit words shorter than a given length?

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like that in your SQL statement

```
= ... LIKE '*access*' or LIKE '*health*'
```